# Tortoise Git seems to connect then refuse my connection: git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, git

I had been using Tortoise Git from my windows PC to connect to GitHub as well as a local server. One of my OS drives failed (raid 0) so now I'm tasked with getting it back up to speed.

I've been trying to connect via ssh for most of the morning but keep getting the following error code:

```
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (12278 ms @ 12/3/2012 4:36:55 PM)
```

I'm fairly certain this isn't a credentials issue as I can connect via terminal on both my Linux box and MacBook. The process prompts for my password then fails with the following error:

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\User\Documents\xxxxxx_docs'...

fatal: '/home/User/repos/xxxxxxx_docs' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It is a git repository and I just cloned it on my Mac. I'm at a loss, any ideas?

Comment: Have the ssh user permissions for reading(/writing) /home/User/repos/xxxxxxx_docs/.git subdirectory?

Comment: I checked permissions, Everything looks good. Also, I'm using the same user to SSH from my Mac, Linux Box and PC. I can push/pull from mac and Linux. if it were a permissions issue wouldn't I have issues from everywhere?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is for every system the same. Please, can you check again URL of remote repository? Is exactly the same, as on the other systems?